# Date from ZonedDateTime instant not in utc

Tags: java, date, timezone

I am creating date like this:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Date.from(now.toInstant());
```

I need Date object have current time in utc, but when I print date it gives me my local time and not utc time.
I also tried with:

```
 OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
 Date date = Date.from(now.toInstant());
```

But when I print Date again time is not in utc. Am I doing something wrong when creating Date object. Why above 2 approaches not give me Date that have current time in utc.

Comment: Why do you need to use `Date` at all? Don't use that class when working with the `java.time` APIs.

Comment: `Date` objects don't have a time zone - they only use the default time zone when printed, as a convenience, but that's it. If you want to print the `Date` with a specific time zone (e.g. UTC) you need top use a DateFormat. Or even better don't use that class at all.

Comment: A `Date` is just a point in time. So it the `Instant` that you use for initializing the date. None of them has got a time zone or offset. The difference here is their `toString` methods: The `Instant` is always printed in UTC, the `Date` usually (always?) in the JVM’s default time zone. The latter confuses many into thinking the `Date` has a time zone when it hasn’t. See [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

Comment: If you need offset, hold on to your `OffsetDateTime` object.

Comment: @ assylias @ Ole V.V. thanks for reply, you are right I have to use DateFormat to set timezone in Date object.

Comment: A `DateFormat` will set the time zone in a string. It cannot and will not set a time zone in the `Date` object since (and I repeat) a `Date` object cannot have a time zone in it. @anujprashar

Comment: Do not mix the troublesome old legacy date-time classes with the java.time classes. The legacy classes are entirely supplanted by java.time, and should be avoided like the Plague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points:

1. Avoid the long outdated `Date` class, in particular when you are already using classes from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.
2. A `Date` object hasn’t got and cannot have a time zone in it.

### To print offset or time zone

If you need your offset, you need to hold on to your `OffsetDateTime` (or `ZonedDateTime`)  object:

```
    OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(now);
```

On my computer this just printed

```
2017-11-21T11:53:11.519Z
```

The `Z` in the end indicates Zulu time zone, another name for UTC (you may also informally think of it as **Z**ero offset from UTC).

If you would like a more human-readable format, you are right, use a formatter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL);
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(now.format(formatter));
```

Depending on your locale and the time, this prints something like

```
Tuesday, November 21, 2017 11:53:11 AM Z
```

Again the `Z` means Zulu time zone, UTC.

### `Date` is not going to help you

A `Date` is just a point in time. So is the `Instant` that you use for initializing the date. None of them has got a time zone or offset. The difference here is their `toString` methods: The `Instant` is always printed in UTC, the `Date` usually (always?) in the JVM’s default time zone. The latter confuses many into thinking the `Date` has a time zone when it hasn’t. See [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

As I have demonstrated, a formatter may put a time zone or offset into a *string* when formatting the date-time. This does not in any way modify the date-time object, whether `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, `Instant` or `Date`. The long outdated `DateFormat` class may do the same when formatting a `Date`. It cannot and will not set a time zone in the `Date` object since (and I repeat) a `Date` object cannot have a time zone in it.

Long story short, you have no need for the outdated `Date` class that I can see.